# how to set isolation level for stored procedure with more transactions

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

My Stored procedure contains 6 begins and 6 ends, so how to change the default REPEATABLE-READ isolation to READ-COMMITTED for the whole stored procedure?

Comment: Why would the transaction level change? btw why do you have more than 1 pair of begin and end. I never get why people do that

Comment: Please add some code example to your question. It is hard to guess what exactly you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could [SET session transaction isolation levels at runtime by using the tx_isolation system variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html)

```
    SELECT @@GLOBAL.tx_isolation, @@tx_isolation;
    SET GLOBAL tx_isolation='REPEATABLE-READ';
    SET SESSION tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED';
```